# Publish to RabbitMQ queue with HTTP API

Tags: rabbitmq

Been going through the documentation (https://cdn.rawgit.com/rabbitmq/rabbitmq-management/v3.7.9/priv/www/api/index.html)

And did not find a way to publish a message to a *queue* (not an exchange, a queue) with the HTTP API?

Is that possible?

As much as it might make little sens in a production mindset, it still can be useful for testing purposes.

I basically want to mimic the “Publish message” interface available in the RabbitMQ administration console.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Note: your question is already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32486629/1466825): [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32486629/1466825)

RabbitMQ only supports publishing to exchanges. This is a *core function* of the product. Then, RabbitMQ uses bindings to figure out what queue(s) should receive the message.

You can read about these concepts [here](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/amqp-concepts.html).

When you use "Publish message" in the administration console, it uses the default binding and default exchange. From [this document](https://www.rabbitmq.com/tutorials/tutorial-three-python.html):

---

## The default exchange

In previous parts of the tutorial we knew nothing about exchanges, but still were able to send messages to queues. That was possible because we were using a default exchange, which we identify by the empty string ("").

Recall how we published a message before:

```
channel.basic_publish(exchange='',
                      routing_key='hello',
                      body=message)
```

The exchange parameter is the name of the exchange. The empty string denotes the default or nameless exchange: messages are routed to the queue with the name specified by routing_key, if it exists.

---

So, in order to *appear* to publish directly to a queue, the management interface publishes a message to the default exchange (named `amq.default` or the empty string `""`) using the queue name as the routing key. You can see this for yourself by enabling the developer tools in your browser and watching the HTTP call made to `/api/exchanges/vhost/name/publish` when you publish a message to a queue.

In your case, the request will look something like this (use Chrome, and right-click the `publish` request and "copy as cUrl"):

```
curl -4vvv -u guest:guest \
    'localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/amq.default/publish' \
    -H 'Content-Type: text/plain;charset=UTF-8' \
    --data-binary '{"vhost":"/","name":"amq.default","properties":{"delivery_mode":1,"headers":{}},"routing_key":"MY-QUEUE-NAME","delivery_mode":"1","payload":"TEST","headers":{},"props":{},"payload_encoding":"string"}'
```

Comment: You can obtain the actual API for your version of RabbitMQ by pointing your browser to http://localhost:15672/api.

Answer (score 3):

For those interested in Intellij IDEA HTTP Client syntax with an array of ids

```
[
  {"id": "83d6e4dc-0478-42da-8da0-65b508530a43"},
  {"id": "08d3e147-79c4-4b91-be7c-b1cc86e21278"}
]

POST http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/amqp.myexchange/publish
Authorization: Basic guest guest
Content-Type: application/json

{
  "vhost": "/",
  "name": "amqp.myexchange",
  "properties": {
    "delivery_mode": 2,
    "headers": {},
    "content_type": "application/json"
  },
  "routing_key": "",
  "delivery_mode": "2",
  "payload": "[{\"id\":\"83d6e4dc-0478-42da-8da0-65b508530a43\"},{\"id\":\"08d3e147-79c4-4b91-be7c-b1cc86e21278\"}]",
  "headers": {},
  "props": {
    "content_type": "application/json"
  },
  "payload_encoding": "string"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

```
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.18\sbin>
C:\Program Files\RabbitMQ Server\rabbitmq_server-3.7.18\sbin>curl -i -u guest:guest localhost:15672/api/exchanges/%2F/amq.default/publish -H 'content-type:application/json" -d '{"vhost":"/","name":"amq.default","properties":{"delivery_mode":1,"headers":{}},"routing_key":"TEST,"delivery_mode":"1","payload":"TEST","headers":{},"props":{},"payload_encoding":"string"}'
HTTP/1.1 405 Method Not Allowed
allow: POST, OPTIONS
content-length: 0
content-security-policy: default-src 'self'
date: Fri, 06 Dec 2019 14:03:08 GMT
server: Cowboy
vary: origin
```

Comment: corrected json: curl -i -u guest:guest localhost:32936/api/exchanges/%2F/amq.default/publish -H "content-type:application/json" -d '{"vhost":"/platform","name":"innovasea","properties":{"delivery_mode":1,"headers":{}},"routing_key":"TEST","delivery_mode":"1","payload":"TESTadf","headers":{},"props":{},"payload_encoding":"string"}'

Answer (score -3):

You are correct. I apologize for the mistake. The password should not be base64-encoded when using the RabbitMQ HTTP API with Postman. Instead, you should use the Basic Authentication feature in Postman to send the credentials.

Here's the corrected step to include the authentication in Postman:

1. Open Postman and create a new request.
2. Set the request method to `POST`.
3. Enter the URL for the RabbitMQ API, including the virtual host and queue name. For example: `http://localhost:15672/api/exchanges/{virtual-host}/{exchange-name}/publish`.

   - Replace `{virtual-host}` with the name of your virtual host. The default virtual host is `/`.
   - Replace `{exchange-name}` with the name of your exchange.
4. Go to the "Headers" section and add the following header:

   - Key: `Content-Type`, Value: `application/json`
5. Click on the "Authorization" tab below the URL input field.
6. Select the "Basic Auth" type.
7. Enter your RabbitMQ username and password in the respective fields.
8. In the request body, select the `raw` option and choose `JSON` from the dropdown.
9. Enter the JSON payload for your message in the request body. For example:

   ```json
   {
     "properties": {},
     "routing_key": "{queue-name}",
     "payload": "Hello, RabbitMQ!",
     "payload_encoding": "string"
   }
   ```

   - Replace `{queue-name}` with the name of your queue.
   - Adjust the payload and payload encoding as per your requirements.
10. Click on the "Send" button to publish the message to the RabbitMQ queue.

Again, I apologize for the confusion caused by the incorrect information in my previous response. Using Basic Authentication in Postman is the appropriate method for sending credentials when using the RabbitMQ HTTP API.

Comment: This answer appears likely to have been written (entirely or partially) by AI (e.g., ChatGPT). If you used an AI tool to assist with any answer, I would encourage you to delete it, as [posting of AI-generated content is banned here](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421831). **Readers should review this answer carefully and critically, as AI-generated information often contains fundamental errors and misinformation.** If you observe quality issues and/or have reason to believe that this answer was AI-generated, please leave feedback accordingly.